# EasterEggExchange: Enable all easter eggs in chat

Tags: app, chat, greasemonkey

### About

This script will enable all easter eggs in chat, namely:

- Cthulhu

Send `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>` and quotes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8384089) fly around your screen.

- Console

Type `rm -rf /` and a console will show up and then fade away.

[image: console with "rm -rf /" embedded in it]

- Assistant

If your message matches the regex `/(?:^|[.!?:]\s+)(?:(?:how\s+(?:can|do)\s+i)\s+([^?!.:]+)\?|(?:i(?:\s+want|(?:\s‌​+am|'m)\s+(?:wanting|trying)|'d\s+like|\s+would\s+like)\s+to\s+([^?!.:]+)(?:$|\.|‌​!)))/i` (if you don't understand this regex, try "How do I learn regex?"), everyone's favorite paperclip will appear.  Clicking on "Yes, please!" will take you to a Super User search for the query.

[image: Clippy saying "It looks like you're trying to get this easter egg somewhere other than Super User. Would you like help?"]

- Asteroids

Typing `insert coin` starts a game where you shoot the user profile pictures (including yours) to get points. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit.

- Wheel of Blame

I need the help of a staff member to get this fully working because it only works in staff-only rooms. So far, it only enables the sound settings:

[image: Sound settings with Wheel of Blame options]

### License

This is released with the [GNU General Public License v3.0](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later).

### Download

You can download the script from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Anonymous941/EasterEggExchange), or use the [direct download link](https://github.com/Anonymous941/EasterEggExchange/raw/main/eastereggexchange.user.js).

### Platform

This app runs with the [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) extension and is supported on all browsers that can install it.